# updateAll() with a join

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii2 I am trying to do an `updateAll` command, but I cannot for the life of me find how to incorporate a `JOIN` into this query.

```
ProjectUser::updateAll(['project_user.is_favorite' => 0],
                       ['project_user.userID' => $methodIDs['user_id'],
                        'project.siteID' => $methodIDs['site_id']
                       ])
                       ->innerJoin('project','project.ID = project_user.projectID')
```

What I am trying to reach is the above, but Yii2 will ignore the join part and give an error because what remains of the query will NOT recognize the `project.siteID` column. How can I get this to work?

As alternative I was thinking to just first do a `findAll`, where the join would work, and update it that way. But how do you update a `findAll()` result which has multiple records in it?

Comment: Ps... Yes I know I actually should fill the variables via the 3rd parameter in the updateAll :P

Comment: I cannot believe that completely writing out a custom update query for this (which would actually be an easy one) is the preferred way when you are using the AR system. Or is it?

Comment: Ok, I ended up applying the solution from the suggested related question anyway. Guess that was the easiest solution, even tho I think it is does look somewhat 'sloppy'.